# Is it possible to make @IBDesignable override Interface Builder values?

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder, ibdesignable

For example, I want to subclass `UIButton` and set it's font to `20.0f` by default. I can write something like this:

```
@IBDesignable

class HCButton: UIButton {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.customInit()
  }

  func customInit () {
    titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
  }
}
```

But this does not affect preview in **Interface Builder**, all custom buttons appear with `15.0f` font size by default. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created new `IBInspectable` as `testFonts` :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.customInit()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.customInit()
    }

    func customInit () {
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
        self.customInit()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.customInit()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.customInit()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you :)

This is working for me.

Comment: Will `@IBInspectable var testFonts: UIFont` appear in Interface Builder?

Comment: @orkenstein No :( It's not displayed. but the font size is changed.

Comment: Remove it from listing and paste `titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)` from original question. It might confuse some wanderer. And thanks for the clue!

Comment: Yes it's ok, The only thing i can dream about now - make this default value replace **Font** value in interface builder.

Comment: Hey, @AshishKakkad, great post! But I notice that `awakeFromNib` function is not needed in my testing to make the `customInit ` setting visible in the interface builder. Is there a reason why you are adding that? Also, I believe `convenience init()` is not needed either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must override the init with frame initializer as well to affect that

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.customInit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EASIER: The following solution usually works or me

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        customInit()
    }

    func customInit () {
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
    }
}
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.